# Exception evaluating SpringEL expression after updating SpringBoot from 2.0.6.RELEASE to 2.1.0.RELEASE

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-el

I had a SpringBoot app with this pom.xml:

```
...
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> 
    </parent>

<!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        </dependency>
...
```

and it was working fine. 
Then I update the SpringBoot version to

```
...
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> 
    </parent>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version> 
        </dependency>
...
```

and I got this error in 1 template:

```
Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#authorization.expression('hasRole(''ROLE_ADMIN'')')" (template: "tdk/common/menu" - line 87, col 21)
```

here the template:

```
 <li th:if="${#authorization.expression('hasRole(''ROLE_ADMIN'')')}"    class="menu-principal pure-menu-item" th:classappend="${activeMenuItem == ‘tdkMessages'} ?  pure-menu-selected">
                    <a href=“/tdk/list" class="pure-menu-link">
                        <i class="fas fa-cloud-download-alt fa-lg fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; tdk
                    </a>
                </li>
```

Comment: You should use the `springsecurity5` dependency from thymeleaf, also the version is managed by Spring Boot.

Comment: @M.Deinum please convert to answer, that was the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thymeleaf now has a special extension/dialect for Spring Security 5. You will need to use that instead of the one for Spring Security 4.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Should do the trick, the `<version>` is managed by Spring Boot so you don't need to add that.